# Where do I find the bookmarks I have made in Google and Gmail

Tags: gmail, google, chrome-bookmarks

I have Google with Gmail and have added bookmarks with the star in the search bar at top of the screen, but I do not know where to find them now. How do I find them?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to do this (I assume you're using Chrome):

Type `chrome://bookmarks` into the browser.

or

Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> on the keyboard and this will make the bookmarks toolbar appear just under the Chrome omnibar (URL bar).

Answer (score 0):

You can click the three bars [image: three-bars icon] on the right side of the omni-bar and choose `bookmarks`.